# Angular subscribe function not being triggered

Tags: angular, http

I have a "Login Component" that initializes variables as :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("at ngOnInit");
    this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log("at subscribe");
        this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response);
      }
    );
    console.log(this.Users);
  }

  handleSuccessfulResponse(response)
  {   
    console.log("handle");
    this.Users=response;
    console.log(this.Users);
  }
```

getUsers() fucntion is as :

```
  getUsers()
  { console.log("at  getUsers");

    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/findalluser');
  }
```

The URL http://localhost:8080/findalluser successfully returns :
[{"id":"1001","username":"ariba","password":"abc"}]

When I login in to the UI with the credentials , I get an error with the following message on console :

```
at ngOnInit
getUsers
undefined
```

and nothing else apart from the error that "this.Users is not iterable" which is justified because this.Users is undefined. Apparently, the "subscribe()" function is not being triggered or maybe the httpClient isn't returning the Observable at all. I can't get why?

**Update :**

Here's the whole Service code -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';


import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

export class Employee{
  constructor(
    public empId:string,
    public name:string,
    public designation:string,
    public salary:string,
  ) {}
}


export class User{
  constructor(
    public id:String,
    public username:string,
    public password:string,

  ) {}
}

export class UssdFiles{
  constructor(
    public filename:string,
    public filepath:string,
  ) {}
}

export class SmsFiles{
  constructor(
    public filename:string,
    public filepath:string,
  ) {}
}

export class Data{
  constructor( public flines: String )
  {}
}

export interface Post{
  id: number;
  userId: string;
  body: string;
  title: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getUsers()
  {   console.log("getUsers");
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/findalluser');
  }

  getUssdFiles(){
    return this.httpClient.get<UssdFiles[]>('http://localhost:8080/findallussd');
  }

  getSmsFiles(){
    return this.httpClient.get<SmsFiles[]>('http://localhost:8080/findallsms');
  }

  getFileData(file:String){
    //const str = JSON.stringify(this.httpClient.get<Data>('http://localhost:8080/getfiledata/'+file));
    return this.httpClient.get<Data>('http://localhost:8080/getfiledata/'+file);
  }

  postFileData(fileData:Object){
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    console.log(fileData)
    return this.httpClient.post<Object>('http://localhost:8080/updatedfiledata',fileData).subscribe(response =>{
      console.log(response);
      //alert("File update successful!")
      if(response==null){
        alert("File update successful!");
      }
  })
  }

}
```

This is what I see in Network Tab on Devtools as I reload my Login page :
[image: network tab]

Comment: Turned out https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837149/8253192 was the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the data within the subscribe code itself,

```
this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe((response) =>{
        console.log("at subscribe");
        console.log(response);
        this.Users=response;
      }
);
```

Comment: Nothing. Doesn't event print "at subscribe"

Comment: Also, I included some tests on HttpClientService for Unit Testing. The tests passed but this code failed. But I never changed anything in this code. Could that affect anyhow??

Comment: i guess the httpClientService is empty, try to debug and see

Comment: I tried debugging. The getUsers()  is being called and so is subscribe but the flow doesn't enter inside the subscribe.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting a response at all fron http

Comment: I just checked, I don't see any http call being made.

Answer (score 0):

Since the subscription is an `Async` process is correct that printing `this.Users` in that part of the code gives you an undefined.

You should see logged that `console.log("at subscribe");` tho.

Put the  `console.log(this.Users);` inside the subscription after the function call

```
this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response);
```

For the API not being called do you see the call in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring users as an empty array to begin with instead of undefined. Assuming you are using *ngFor in the DOM and undefined can't be iterated over.

The HTTP request is async so it won't necessarily complete before the DOM renders. If you define users as a blank array it can iterate over this until your users come from server.

`public users: Array<User> = [];`

Comment: this.Users is now [ ] (empty) instead of "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your method like this

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]>
{ 
  console.log("at  getUsers");
  return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/findalluser');
}
```